# How to append it after Python list check in CSV value?

Tags: python, list

I want to compare one of list which it is to be or not in CSV row[0].

For example,

`A = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']`

`result = []`

and

CSV file's row[0] has many words. If one of A is same to one of CSV's row[0] then want to append value of row[0] to result list.

How to make it?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBxbj.png)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

A = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana']
res = []
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv')
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.loc[i].item in A:
        res.append(df.loc[i].item, df.loc[i].count, df.loc[i].place)
```

You can append only the values you want to the variable res.
Hope this helps and do comment if you find any errors.

Answer (score 0):

```py
if isinstance(row[0], list):
    if set(A) & set(row[0]):
         result.append(row[0])
else:
    for word in A:
        if word in row[0]:
            result.append(row[0])
            break
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.